# Identify the status of the word-final -s

Tags: morphology, word-formation

I don't understand this question, but we have to classify if each word-final -s or -er is not a suffix or if it is an inflectional or derivational suffix. I specifically don't understand the wording "word-final." I put that, for example, that in the word kiss, the "word-final -s" is not a suffix where-as the "word-final -s" in the word "brings" is an inflectional suffix. Is that correct? When is the word-final -s not inflectional if it is a suffix?

Comment: As far as  can see, your understanding of it is right.

Answer (score 1):

In English, that would be when word-final -*s* as a suffix is derivational, not inflectional. Examples would be *forwards, backwards, sideways, besides*. Also there is an endearative use in *pops, toots* (although *toot* = [tʊt] is not used by itself).

Comment: "***an inflectional or derivational suffix ...When is the word-final -s not inflectional if it is a suffix?***" --> Your answer: "***that would be when word-final -s as a suffix is derivational, not inflectional***." It might be quite helpful if you explained for novice linguists why *towards* has a derivational suffix, perhaps? Otherwise your answer is kind of just an example, without any explanation.

Comment: I don;t see how those are *derivational* (because I don;t know and you didn;t explain what that means). To me, as a German speaker, your examples look like genitive inflection, and wiktionary agrees (cf. besides, from genitive noun inflection [of *side*, obviously], comparable to possessive *'s*). Is *pants* plural (or genitive), or, in your view, derivational? Historic Linguistic's calls these forms *fossilized*.

Comment: I guess the main question is whether you understand the term "derivational" as opposed to "inflectional", and accept that it is a valid distinction. You could just say that all affixation is inflectional, so by definition anything that is suffixal is inflectional. I'm not arguing that "derivational" is a valid distinction, but the OP presupposes that it is.